# How display tooltip for each point of a line chart using Echarts (JS)

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a question about the Echarts library https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/index.html.

I'm using Echarts to draw a line chart from a series of points (x,y) and I want to display the coordinates (x,y) of each point in the drawn line chart when the user hovers over the mouse on the point as tooltip the problem that I found is that I can display only for the points given in entered and not for the totality of line that is to say I cannot display the coordinates of a point between two successive points given in input.

how can I display the tooltip for each point of the graph as tooltip?

I have used this JSON object as an option object to pass it as a parameter to the setOption method.

```
       {
        tooltip: {
            type: 'item'
        },
        grid: {
            left: '3%',
            right: '4%',
            bottom: '3%',
            containLabel: true,
            show: true,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",

        },
        toolbox: {
            feature: {
                dataZoom: {
                    title: {
                        zoom: "zoom by rectangle",
                        back: "undo zooming"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'value',
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'value',
            triggerEvent: true
        },
        dataZoom: [{
                type: 'inside',
                xAxisIndex: [0],
                moveOnMouseMove: true,
            },
            {
                type: 'inside',
                yAxisIndex: [0],
                moveOnMouseMove: true,
            }
        ],
        series: [{
            name: "line1",
            data: [
                [1.5, 10],
                [5, 7],
                [8, 8],
                [12, 6],
                [11, 12],
                [16, 9],
                [14, 6],
                [17, 4],
                [19, 9]
            ],
            type: 'line',
        }]
    };
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code for reference and for a better answer?

Comment: I added the object that I used to draw the line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to your problem would be to change the tooltip option to set the type to `cross`. It would look something like this -

```
tooltip: {
        axisPointer: {
                type: 'cross'
            }
    }
```

This type of display is particularly helpful when you are using orthometric axis as it displays the location of the mouse.

Echarts Docs for tooltip: https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#tooltip.axisPointer.type

Comment: Thank you Urmil Ashish Parikh for this quick response, it solves a part of my problem. Indeed, I want to show the tooltip not for all points in the grid just for the drawn line chart and I ant I want the tooltip to appear on the point of the line not on the x, y axes.

Comment: I don't think echarts supports such a thing. Also, it doesn't make any sense because in line chart, only the data points are the thing of interest. The line is just used to analyse whether there's a growth or fall. The points on that line should not be of any value.

Comment: If you want to do it that way, you can create a function which generates an equation of line from the 2 points and then randomly generates about 100 points on that line. Add those points to data field in options. It should solve your issue. But I think you should do it the way I mentioned in the answer instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

just add below tooltip configuration
then it should work

```
tooltip: {
      type: 'item'
}
```

```
options: EChartsOption = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
    },
    yAxis: {
      type: 'value',
    },
    series: [
      {
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line',
      },
    ],
    tooltip: {
      type: 'item'
    }
  };
```